# Comparing two strings with Jasper inner function EXACT

Tags: jasper-reports

When I try to compare two values I have an error

ERROR PrintJasperService:338 - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException:
Error evaluating expression for source text: //EXACT($P{id}, "14" ) ? "FLASH" :$P{name}

$P{id} I get out from an array: $P{map}.get("{id}")==null? " ":$P{map}.get("{id}")
So value of $P{id} can not be NULL.
The type of $P{id} is java.lang.String.

I tried compare with 'equals' but got the same error:
ERROR PrintJasperService:338 - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException:
Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{id}.equals("14") ? "FLASH" :$P{name}

What I do wrong?

Comment: You shoud post small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue

Comment: Also post the full exception stacktrace, including "Caused by ..." lines

Comment: When I did small jrxml as asked @Alex K I saw that in this small report all this functions are working. So reason is in data after getting it from map array. "id" in array is as integer, but I saved it after getting out from array as class java.lang.String and if you only display this parameter then everything works but in conditions I couldn`t use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the parameter as java.lang.String would not convert the value to String, you'll need to make sure that the parameter expression evaluates to a String.

You can use something like this:

`$P{map}.get("{id}")==null? " ":$P{map}.get("{id}").toString()`